# Is it okay to call +[NSData dataWithData:] with an NSMutableData object?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsdata, nsmutabledata

Is it a problem for me to do the following to change a mutable data instance immutable?

```
NSMutableData *mutData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
//Giving some value to mutData
NSData *immutableData = [NSData dataWithData:mutData];
[mutData release];
```

Answer (score 11):

This is completely okay, and is in fact one of the primary uses of `dataWithData:` -- to create an immutable copy of a mutable object.*

`NSData` also conforms to the [`NSCopying` protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCopying_Protocol/),** which means you could instead use `[mutData copy]`. The difference is that `dataWithData:` returns an object you do not own (it is autoreleased), whereas [per memory management rules](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MemoryManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008195-CH27-SW3), `copy` creates an object for whose memory you *are* responsible. `dataWithData:` is equivalent in effect to `[[mutData copy] autorelease]`.

So you can choose either `dataWithData:` or `copy`, dependent upon your requirements for the lifetime of the resulting object.

---

*This also applies to similar methods in other classes which have a mutable subclass, e.g., `+[NSArray arrayWithArray:]`.

**See also ["Object Copying"](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/ObjectCopying.html) in the Core Competencies Guide.

Answer (score 4):

No it is not a problem. `immutableData` will be initialized with the data in `mutData`.